# Problema con impresión de arrays generados con métodos static

Tags: java, array, java-ee, ordenamiento

Tengo un programa el cual tiene dos clases, una llamada `UtilesArrays`, la cual contiene estos dos métodos:

```
public static int[] arrayRandomLimitesOrdenado(int[] arrayEntrada){

    for(int i=0; i<arrayEntrada.length/2;i++) {
        int auxiliar = arrayEntrada[i];
        arrayEntrada[i]=arrayEntrada[arrayEntrada.length-1-i];
        arrayEntrada[arrayEntrada.length-1-i]=auxiliar;
    }

    return arrayEntrada;
    }

public static int[] arrayRandomLimites(int longitud, int max, int min) {
    int[] arrayRandom = new int[longitud];

    for(int i=0;i<arrayRandom.length;i++) {
        arrayRandom[i]=(int)(randomLimites(max,min));
    }

    return arrayRandom;
}

public static void mostrar(int[] arr) {
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Para utilizar estos lo hago desde otra clase lanzador con su método `main`. Pues bien, si lo hago en este orden, e imprimo los datos:

```
    int[] array1 = UtilesArrays.arrayRandomLimites(5,20,3);
    int[] array2 = UtilesArrays.arrayRandomLimitesOrdenado(array1);
    UtilesArrays.mostrar(array1);
    UtilesArrays.mostrar(array2);
```

Se imprime dos veces el mismo `array1`, pero si lo hago en este otro orden:

```
    int[] array1 = UtilesArrays.arrayRandomLimites(5,20,3);
    UtilesArrays.mostrar(array1);
    int[] array2 = UtilesArrays.arrayRandomLimitesOrdenado(array1);
    UtilesArrays.mostrar(array2);
```

Se imprime el primero random y el segundo ordenado.

¿Qué se me está escapando?

Comment: Deberias poner tu funcion randomLimites.  Tambien en tu segundo ejemplo, muestras array2 antes que este definido

Answer (score 2):

Es interesante lo que comentas Adrián y es algo que tal vez todos los que usamos java en algún momento nos sucedio, el problema aquí es que tu método `arrayRandomLimitesOrdenado()` usa los valores del Array  arrayEntrada pero usas este mismo array para modificar sus valores, lo cual es incorrecto:

```
public static int[] arrayRandomLimitesOrdenado(int[] arrayEntrada){

    for(int i=0; i<arrayEntrada.length/2;i++) {
        int auxiliar = arrayEntrada[i];
        arrayEntrada[i]=arrayEntrada[arrayEntrada.length-1-i];
        arrayEntrada[arrayEntrada.length-1-i]=auxiliar;
    }

    return arrayEntrada;
    }
```

lo que se debe realizar es crear un nuevo array, en este caso `arraySalida`  en el cual se agregarían las modificaciones:

```
   public static int[] arrayRandomLimitesOrdenado(int[] arrayEntrada){

     //Crea un array para almacenar los valores de tu operación.
     int[]  arraySalida = new int[arrayEntrada.length]; //*

     for(int i=0; i<arrayEntrada.length/2;i++) {
        int auxiliar = arrayEntrada[i];

        arraySalida[i]=arrayEntrada[arrayEntrada.length-1-i]; //*
        arraySalida[arrayEntrada.length-1-i]=auxiliar; //*

      }

      return arraySalida; //*
    }
```

De esta forma no tendrás el problema que comentas, que te muestre los mismos valores.

Answer (score -1):

Muchas gracias por tu respuesta @Jorgesys , aunque no era correcta 100% solo le faltaba un pequeño detalle!

En arrays de longitud par funciona perfectamente, pero en arrays de longitudes impares la posición central se quedaba sin asignar, lo he clonando en primer lugar el array de entrada y ya trabajando con él:

```
    public static int[] arrayRandomLimitesOrdenado(int[] arrayEntrada){
    int[] arraySalida= arrayEntrada.clone();


    for(int i=0; i<arrayEntrada.length/2;i++) {
        int auxiliar = arraySalida[i];
        arraySalida[i]=arraySalida[arraySalida.length-1-i];
        arraySalida[arraySalida.length-1-i]=auxiliar;
    }

    return arraySalida;
    }
```

Comment: Por eso es importante agregat los datos necesarios, un usuario preguntaba acerca de la función randomLimites, esto para saber que datos esperar.

Comment: Gracias de nuevo @jorgeSys era mi primera pregunta y todavía estoy familiarizandome con todo esto... espero ir mejorando, muchisimas gracias!

Comment: Perfecto @AdriánC , hay que aportar datos necesarios y tendrás muchas buenas respuestas, te invito a realizar el [tour] del sitio!, para preguntar es bueno leas [ask] para que formules tu pregunta y obtengas la ayuda necesaria, saludos!